# Grab compound nodes when a child node is grabbed

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm currently trying to implement the developp the following behavior in my application embedding Cytoscape.js : I would like that when a particular child node of a compound node  is grabbed,  the whole compound node is grabbed.
If tried using this code but it does not work as I expect :

```
cy.$(mySubNodeSelector)
                        .on('grab', function(){ 
                            this.ungrabify();
                            this.parent().select();
                            this.parent().grabify();
                        });
```

Does anybody has an advice about how to implement this behavior ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable events on the child: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/events

Your code doesn't do anything because (1) you're mutating grabbability after elements have been grabbed and (2) you conflate grabifying (allowing grabbing) with grabbing (a user gesture).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I understand. Now it works as expected.